# Only select unique record for a condition in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

How can i select only distinct user id's ONLY having ACCESS_COLUMN_ID value 1 even though they may also have ACCESS_COLUMN_ID value 2 as well.

Here is my query which returns 1 and 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(USER_ID) FROM USER_ACCESS WHERE ACCESS_COLUMN_ID = 1
```

The result returned contains userid who have `ACCESS_COLUMN_ID = 2` as well.

```html
Here is my table data

USERID ACCESS_COLUMN_ID 
1          1
1          2
2          1
```

I am expecting USERID 2 only as my query result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT    USER_ID
FROM      USER_ACCESS 
GROUP  BY USER_ID
HAVING    MIN(ACCESS_COLUMN_ID) = 1
AND       MAX(ACCESS_COLUMN_ID) = 1
```

This query will get all `user_id`, but only unique ones because of the `group by` clause. Then it will take the minimum and maximum `access_column_id` it finds for each of them, and if these two values are both 1, then the `user_id` is retained in the final result set.

The above will have good performance, as it references the table only once.

For your interest, there are several other ways to get the same result. However they all need the table to be referenced twice. You might want to compare their readability and performance yourself:

**NOT EXISTS**

```
SELECT    DISTINCT USER_ID
FROM      USER_ACCESS UA1
WHERE     UA1.ACCESS_COLUMN_ID = 1
AND       NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM   USER_ACCESS UA2
              WHERE  UA1.USER_ID = UA2.USER_ID
              AND    UA2.ACCESS_COLUMN_ID <> 1)
```

**NOT IN**

This is very similar to the previous one, but in my experience has not as good performance:

```
SELECT    DISTINCT USER_ID
FROM      USER_ACCESS
WHERE     ACCESS_COLUMN_ID = 1
AND       USER_ID NOT IN (
              SELECT USER_ID
              FROM   USER_ACCESS
              WHERE  ACCESS_COLUMN_ID <> 1)
```

**Outer Self-Join**

This often has better performance than the previous two solutions:

```
SELECT    DISTINCT USER_ID
FROM      USER_ACCESS UA1
LEFT JOIN USER_ACCESS UA2
       ON UA1.USER_ID = UA2.USER_ID
      AND UA2.ACCESS_COLUMN_ID <> 1
WHERE     UA1.ACCESS_COLUMN_ID = 1
AND       UA2.USER_ID IS NULL
```

The last `NULL` condition checks that the outer join did not yield any match (with `ACCESS_COMUN_ID <> 1`).

**EXCEPT**

This is syntax specific to SQL Server, but is easy to understand (Oracle has the similar `MINUS`);

```
SELECT    DISTINCT USER_ID
FROM      USER_ACCESS
WHERE     ACCESS_COLUMN_ID = 1
EXCEPT
SELECT    USER_ID
FROM      USER_ACCESS
WHERE     ACCESS_COLUMN_ID <> 1
```

**Remark on DISTINCT**

The `DISTINCT` keyword is easy to understand, but one might often get better performance by using a `GROUP BY` clause instead. This can be applied to all solutions mentioned above.

If it is certain that there cannot be two records with the same values for `USER_ID` and `ACCESS_COLUMN_ID` then the `DISTINCT` keyword can be left out in the above queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT IN` to filter out the ones with `ACCESS_COLUMN_ID = 2`

```
SELECT DISTINCT(USER_ID) FROM USER_ACCESS WHERE ACCESS_COLUMN_ID = 1 and 
USER_ID NOT IN (
  SELECT DISCTINCT (USER_ID) FROM USER_ACCESS WHERE ACCESS_COLUMN_ID = 2
)
```

Comment: Will SQL Server cache the results of the sub-select? If so, that might be a performance issue at some scale point.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways you could complete this task. This is probably the most flexible.

Get a list of all the users with the desired access ID, and bounce it against the list of users with the access IDs that are not desired. This has the benefit of being extensible.

```
SELECT * FROM USER_ACCESS u1
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT USER_ID FROM USER_ACCESS 
     WHERE ACCESS_COLUMN_ID NOT IN ($IDsGoHere$)) u2
ON u1.USER_ID = u2.USER_ID
WHERE u1.ACCESS_COLUMN_ID IN ($IDsGoHere$) AND
u2.USER_ID IS NULL;
```

A few key points:

- The query may benefit from the subselect table `u2` MAY being `DISTINCT`. It depends on the number of results returned.
- If you wanted to see all the users who have access A, but don't have access B, you could replace the sub-select's `WHERE NOT IN` clause accordingly.

I don't know how SQLServer handles optimization, but I've seen systems where a performance gain was found replacing the `IN (X)` and `NOT IN (X)` with `= X` and `!= X` respectively.

## Edit 1 - General Thinking around WHERE clauses

As a general rule of thumb, it's always good to consider whether you need to consult other rows not in scope of the generated row in calculating your response. If you do (as in this case, where the row had to be present, and other rows were absent for the same `USER_ID`), it's generally a sign you need to introduce a join of some sort to eliminate the results you don't want.